# Need to change the file name (excel) using xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, bcp

In a file path (**c:\Test\**), I have an EXCEL file named as "**SundayReport(WTD and MTD).xls**"

I need to rename the file to "**SundayReport_WTD_MTD).xls**" using **xp_cmdshell**.

Kindly suggest me how to change the name.

Comment: I am getting Syntax Error . I need the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `RENAME` dos-command would do. Type `RENAME /?` in Windows command shell (cmd.exe), see how you should run the command.
2. Then format the command as you need it in an VARCHAR (eg `@cmd`) and execute it as `EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd;`.

---

Eg

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(8000);
SET @cmd='RENAME "C:\Test\SundayReport(WTD and MTD).xls" "SundayReport_WTD_MTD).xls"';
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

Comment: thanks for your support . But at the time of execute the Script "**output
The system cannot find the file specified.**" message showing.    But I check the file path is correct.

Comment: What happens if you run the rename command from command prompt (cmd.exe)? Maybe the file name itself is similar but just a tad different? FYI I quickly ran this test command on a dummy file on my pc, and it works.

Comment: Is the file on the same machine as the SQL Server?  xp_CmdShell runs on the server.  You need to provide a file address that can be seen from the server.

Comment: @destination-data Good point. @Tapas: If the file is on another computer than the database server, you need to provide a suitable path for the server to find the file. Eg by providing the internet-address like `\\10.0.0.1\share_name\file_name`.

Comment: Thanks TT for your support

Comment: Yes .. thank  you .. it is working fine...As My DB and File path server is in different location , I was facing issues.